# Idiomatic way to add two pandas Series objects with different indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Series objects that I would like to add:

`s1 = Series([1,1], index=['a', 'b'])`

`s2 = Series([2.2], index=['x', 'y'])`

When I add them, I get a Series with 4 elements with NaN values, but what I want is a Series that is `[s1.a + s2.x, s1.b + s2.y]`.  This seems like it should be possible, because the indices have an ordering.

I can get what I want from `pd.Series(s1.values + s2.values)`, but I'd like to know if there is a function that already operates on the Series objects this way and returns a series, rather than having to go down to numpy.

Comment: What do you want the resulting index to be? `[a,b]` or `[x, y]`?

Comment: I hadn't considered that. The new series has a new meaning, so it might be good to have a new index. But if I had to choose from the existing indices, in my application ['a', 'b'] is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what do you want for the final index:

```
In [20]:

s1+s2.values
Out[20]:
a    3
b    3
dtype: int64
In [21]:

s2+s1.values
Out[21]:
x    3
y    3
dtype: int64
```

Or even `multiindex`:

```
In [22]:
s3=s2+s1.values
s3.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(s1.index, s2.index))
s3
Out[22]:
a  x    3
b  y    3
dtype: int64
```